# How can i filter messages on redis-cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am storing messages in JSON format on redis. Is there any way to filter those messages from redis-cli on the basis of attribute values?

Comment: Are you using RedisJSON?

Comment: Nope, storing as plain json data. Is it possible if i use RedisJSON?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/